# SQL ON DELETE CASCADE based on a condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, foreign-keys

I have two tables which are linked with the foreign key in the Staff member table. I'm trying to setup the foreign key so that a row in the position table is removed if it has no associated staff members from the Staff Member table. I am using ON DELETE CASCADE however this removes the row even if there are still staff members associated with the position.

```
Position Table
----------------------------------------------
----Attribute-------Type-------------Keys-----
----------------------------------------------
-    Title     -- VARCHAR(20)  --Primary Key--
-    MaxSalary -- DECIMAL(8,2) --     No     -
-    MinSalary -- DECIMAL(8,2) --     No     -
----------------------------------------------

StaffMember Table
-----------------------------------------------------
----Attribute-------Type-----------------Keys--------
-----------------------------------------------------
-    StaffNo    -- INTEGER     --    Primary Key   --
-    Name       -- VARCHAR(20) --         No        -
-    Salary     -- DECIMAL(8,2)--         No        -
-    StaffTitle -- VARCHAR(20) --FK Position(Title) -
-----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE StaffMember(
StaffNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(20),
Salary DECIMAL(8,2),
StaffTitle VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Position(Title) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're doing exactly the opposite from what you'd want to.

`ON DELETE CASCADE` is used if you want to remove both master and detail rows using a single `DELETE` command, i.e. deleting a master will delete all its details.

You said you want to prevent it from happen.

So - remove that option from the constraint statement, i.e.

```
stafftitle varchar2(20) constraint fk_staff_position references position (title)
```

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table position (title varchar2(20) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table staffmember
  2    (staffno    integer primary key,
  3     name       varchar2(20),
  4     salary     decimal (8, 2),
  5     stafftitle varchar2(20) constraint fk_staff_pos references position (title)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into position (title) values ('some title');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into staffmember (staffno, name, salary, stafftitle)
  2    values (1, 'name', 100, 'some title');

1 row created.

SQL> delete from position;
delete from position
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_STAFF_POS) violated - child record found


SQL>
```

See? You can't delete master as long as detail exists.

Comment: I actually want the row in the master table to de deleted only if the last entry linked to it is deleted from the child table. For example if there is one entry in the position table with one entry in the StaffMember table linked to it, I wanted the entry in the position table to be deleted if the last remaining staff member is removed.

Comment: Cascading works from master to detail, not vice versa.